# Automatically Creating or Inserting Table Rows Based on Advanced Filter VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I'm relatively new to VBA but i spent countless hours learning about Advance Filter using VBA but i cant seem to figure out how to write a copy that determine how many rows are within the result of the filter data and then use that information to resize/create additional rows for a table.

So basically i have Sheet1 with a table named RT which will used to filter down using criteria table under sheet name(Criteria Config) on A3 with current region then im telling the code to output the filter data to Sheet3 under Table4 but i would like automatically add or inset additional columns if necessarry.

Now, once i have this working i was wondering if ontop of this code, if i can have another table from Sheet2 to filter down and output to Sheet3 under new table(below Table 4) but the code needs to know what range or cell to paste the data, my issue would be how to determine where to paste the data based on how many rows are in the first table(table4)

I'm doing my best since i been learning VBA code for the past 2-3 days but i hit roadblock...

**My main goal is automatically create a code that automatically create additional rows if necessarry based on the filter data to the table.**

Here is my code to use Advanced Filter and Copy Filtered Data

```
Sub UseAdvancedFilterCopy1()
    Dim rt As Range
    Dim ct As Range
    Dim out As Range
    Dim tb As ListObject
    Dim tc As ListObject
    Dim ta As ListObject
 
    Set tb = Sheet3.ListObjects("Table4")
    Set tc = Sheet1.ListObjects("RT")
    Set rt = tc.Range
    Set ct = Sheet4.Range("A3").CurrentRegion
    Set out = tb.Range
    rt.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, ct, out
End Sub
```

Here is my code to clear filter and clear contents from the table in case anyone finds any flaws

```
Sub ClearFilter()
    If Sheet1.FilterMode = True Then
        Sheet1.ShowAllData
    End If
End Sub
```

```
Sub ClearTable()
On Error Resume Next
Sheet3.ListObjects("Table4").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
End Sub
```

- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 
- 

***UPDATED INFORMATION BELOW****

***VERSION 1****

I ended up changing my code and my sheets to use no tables since it was bit extra of code and it wasnt really needed. This allows the code to run better i think. I'm a newbie to this, been learning vba code for the past 5 days.

I have a sub calling 2 advanced filters subs

> **THE CALLING**

```
Sub Filters()

Call AdvancedFilter
Call AdvancedFilterQC

End Sub
```

> **TABLE 1**

```
 Sub AdvancedFilter()
        Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Range("A23:I23"), Sheet3.Range("A23:J23").End(xlDown)).Clear 
'This helps clear the table completely after every run

        Dim source1 As Range
        Dim criteria1 As Range
        Dim output1 As Range
        Set source1 = Sheet1.ListObjects("RT").Range
        Set criteria1 = Sheet4.Range("A3").CurrentRegion
        Set output1 = Sheet3.Range("B22").CurrentRegion
        source1.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, criteria1, output1
    End Sub
```

> **TABLE 2**

**This is the code i truly need help with**

```
Sub AdvancedFilterQC()
            Dim output1 As Range
            Dim qcheader As Range
            Set output1 = Sheet3.Range("B22").CurrentRegion
            With output1
                Set qcheader = .Offset(.Rows.Count + 1)
            End With
            Sheet4.Range("F19:J19").Copy qcheader
'The code above just read how many rows are in the Table 1 then copy the headers of table 2 after the lastrow + 1 
    
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
'Gave it a delay to avoid conflict but doesnt seem help
 
           Dim source2 As Range
            Dim criteria2 As Range
            Dim output2 As Range
            Set source2 = Sheet2.ListObjects("QCT").Range
            Set criteria2 = Sheet4.Range("A9").CurrentRegion
            With qcheader
                Set output2 = .Offset(.Rows.Count + 1)
            End With
            source2.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, criteria2, output2
'After this line, i get an error code Run-time error '1004: Application-defined or object-defined error
    
End Sub
```

Just bit more of information, i cant tell you the exact rows of table1 because the table has to be dynamic due to different filters

Then headers get created after the last row + 1 row. The reason why im copying these headers is because i havent found a way to output filter data in the specific headers i want.

Then i want to output the filter data through the headers and below

**IMPORTANT INFORMATION**

**TABLE1**

| Source | Date Added to X | Date Added to Y | Item# | OnCall Date | Action Date | Request# | Date Added to Z | Model ID | SKU ID | Product Name | Company Name | Status | Assignment | Incident | Comments | Completed Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |
| x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |

**TABLE1[Filtered Data]**

| Action Date | Assignment | Request# | Product Name | Model ID | Status | OnCall Date | Item# |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |
| x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |

**TABLE2**

| Request# | Date Pending X | Completed by | TX Assignment | TX Status | Comments | Additional Comments | TX Completion Date | TX More Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |
| x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x |

**TABLE2[Filtered Data]**

| Date Pending X | Completed by | TX Assignment | TX Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | x | x | x |
| x | x | x | x |

_
_
_
_
_
_
_
_

_
_
_
_

_
_
_
_

_
_
_
_
_
_
_
_

_
_
_
_

***UPDATED INFORMATION BELOW****

***VERSION 2****

Thanks to @taller, i made amazing progress to the code. Your update 2 was amazing but it was missing a few details to make it work correctly. Please review and see the code below

> **THE CALLING**

```
Sub Filters()

Call AdvancedFilter
Call AdvancedFilterQC

End Sub
```

> **TABLE 1**

```
 Sub AdvancedFilter()
        Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Range("A23:I23"), Sheet3.Range("A23:J23").End(xlDown)).Clear 
'This helps clear the table completely after every run

        Dim source1 As Range
        Dim criteria1 As Range
        Dim output1 As Range
        Set source1 = Sheet1.ListObjects("RT").Range
        Set criteria1 = Sheet4.Range("A3").CurrentRegion
        Set output1 = Sheet3.Range("B22").CurrentRegion
        source1.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, criteria1, output1
    End Sub
```

> **TABLE 2**

```
        Sub AdvancedFilterQC()
        Dim output1 As Range
Dim qctitle As Range
        Dim qcheader As Range
        Set output1 = Sheet3.Range("B22").CurrentRegion
        With output1
            With output1
        Set qctitle = .Offset(.Rows.Count + 1).Cells(1, 2) 
        Set qcheader = .Offset(.Rows.Count + 2).Cells(1, 2)

' I added a title row above and Added cell 1,2 to 
' adjust to the correct the columns because i wanted 
' to sit in middle more than left side'

        End With
    Sheet4.Range("F18:I18").Copy qctitle
    Sheet4.Range("F19:I19").Copy qcheader
' I added this because we need those headers for the 
' table2 otherwise it will copy all columns which i 
' dont want' and title gets copied too. I'm sure i can 
' use the same name and combine the range but in case 
' i decide to change the title location is easier this 
' way.


        Dim source2 As Range
        Dim criteria2 As Range
        Dim output2 As Range
        Set source2 = Sheet2.ListObjects("QCT").Range
        Set criteria2 = Sheet4.Range("A9").CurrentRegion
    Set output2 = qcheader.CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0)
' modified the output2 to ensure the output was using
' the headers i copied, the previous code wasnt
' working correctly. I also added currentregion to
' ensure it can read all the headers


        source2.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, criteria2, output2
    End Sub
```

Now everything is working as expected. However, I noticed 2 different behaviors i have questions on in order to perfect this task.

**FOLLOW UP QUESTIONS**

1. Is possible to add a column within the headers thats not relevant to the output2 from source2. Meaning i would like to have a column in the middle named "xxxx" which i will use to formulate my own formulas seperate after the data is filtered
2. Is it possible to code with the script to automatically disable alerts and continue the script? For example I receive the following message "The Destination range is not large enough to accommodate all copied rows. Data below the destination range will be lost. Continue copying anyway?

Once i click yes, the script continues. or is there solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Assumes `Sheet2` with a table named `RT2`, it is filtered with same criteria as `RT1`
- `NewTable` is created at a row below `Table4`

```vb
Sub UseAdvancedFilterCopy1()
    Dim rt As Range
    Dim ct As Range
    Dim out As Range
    Dim tb As ListObject
    Dim tc As ListObject
    Dim ta As ListObject
 
    Set tb = Sheet3.ListObjects("Table4")
    Set tc = Sheet1.ListObjects("RT")
    Set rt = tc.Range
    Set ct = Sheet4.Range("A3").CurrentRegion
    Set out = tb.Range
    rt.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, ct, out

    Dim tc2 as ListObject, out2 as Range
    Set tc2 = Sheet2.ListObjects("RT2") ' modify table name as needed
    With tb.Range
        Set out2 = .Cells(1).Offset(.Rows.Count + 1)
    End With
    tc2.Range.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=ct, CopyToRange:=out2
    Sheet3.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, out2.CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = "NewTable"    
End Sub
```

---

*Update:*

```vb
Sub UseAdvancedFilterCopy1()
    Dim rt As Range
    Dim ct As Range
    Dim out As Range
    Dim tb As ListObject
    Dim tc As ListObject
    Dim ta As ListObject
 
    Set tb = Sheet3.ListObjects("Table4")
    Set tc = Sheet1.ListObjects("RT")
    Set ct = Sheet4.Range("A3").CurrentRegion
    Set out = tb.Range.Cells(1)
    tb.Range.Clear
    tc.Range.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, ct, out
    Sheet3.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, out.CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = "Table4"

    Dim tc2 as ListObject, out2 as Range
    Set tc2 = Sheet2.ListObjects("RT2") ' modify table name as needed
    With Sheet3.ListObjects("Table4").Range
        Set out2 = .Cells(1).Offset(.Rows.Count + 1)
    End With
    tc2.Range.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=ct, CopyToRange:=out2
    Sheet3.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, out2.CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = "Table5"    
End Sub
```

---

*Update2:*

> Question:  table1 works perfectly but table2 doesnt look correctly

```vb
Sub AdvancedFilterQC()
    Dim output1 As Range
    Dim qcheader As Range
    Set output1 = Sheet3.Range("B22").CurrentRegion
    With output1
        Set qcheader = .Offset(.Rows.Count + 1).Cells(1) ' **
    End With

    Dim source2 As Range
    Dim criteria2 As Range
    Dim output2 As Range
    Set source2 = Sheet2.ListObjects("QCT").Range
    Set criteria2 = Sheet4.Range("A9").CurrentRegion
    With qcheader
        Set output2 = .Offset(.Rows.Count + 1)
    End With
    source2.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, criteria2, output2 
End Sub
```

Comment: I get Invalid Procedure call or argument. 

Also is there way to automatically resize or add additional rows to 'Table4' because when data is copied and output to the 'Table4' i get the following message

"The destination range is not large enough to accommdate all copied rows. Data below the destination range will be lost. Continue Copying anyway? Yes or No.

If i click on Yes, it will paste the data after the table and table remain the same size

Comment: Your code has the issue.  I've refactored your code. Please try the updated code. What's the top-left cell location of Table4? Is there any data on Sheet3 before runing the code?

Comment: Hey, I ended up updating my code, the code you gave me didnt really work correctly. I ended up doing more research and working on different method but i need help with creating table 2. Look above for the update information. Your assistance is definitely appreciative!

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `didnt really work correctly`. Edit your post to share data (table) layout is helpful for troubleshooting. `xlFilterCopy` copies the header from source table (ListObject).

Comment: TABLE1 runs from Column A-G but headers are already on the output sheet  from Column B-I

TABLE2 originally runs from A-I columns but i'm selecting specific headers which i copy and paste to the output sheet that only runs on Column C-F

Comment: Your code didnt doesnt allow to be re-run, it complete delete the table. Also Table2 overlaps at time after i manually clear the table due to the code running at the same time or running to fast. Also If you can re-create the code to copy specific headers for table2 meaning that the code have to copy whatever headers you want after lastrow + 1 row after table1 then run another advanced filter for table2 using those headers then that would be great!

Comment: I updated the post with layout of table1 & table2 and also how it should look like after filtered data. I want to state that table1 works perfectly but table2 doesnt look correctly

Comment: Please try `update2`.

Comment: It was missing a few things. I'm going to update my post but i have a question, my question will be included on my updated post. Give me 1-2 minutes to update the post.

Comment: Hey @taller, i updated the posts. Thank you. If you can review and advice 

Comment: Question1: Yes, you can add a column in the table on the destination worksheet. Question2: `Set output2 = qcheader.CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Cells(1)` Let `output2` equals to the top-left cell of destination table.  btw, 
[What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: I wasnt able to paste a column none related to output data in the destination worksheet. I included a code that after advancedfilter was done then it create insert or paste a column. my follow up question is under https://stackoverflow.com/q/77744000/23177311 to ensure im following guidelines of stackoverflow. 
-
-