# Copying Formula with Square Brackets [ ] & Dynamic Cell Reference using VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365, copy-paste

I'm currently trying to basically copy a formula down with cell reference that should dynamic but its not working. I tried so many things but i just want to introduce myself and say i been coding vba for the past 5 days so im no expert, please forgive me if my code is not optimized or better. If you have better ideas, let me know.

The Formula I want to across the range is

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Request Tracker'!$K:$K,MATCH(Email.Template!E14,'Request Tracker'!$G:$G,0)),"")`

**The code that i need help with**

```
name2.CurrentRegion.Offset(2, 4).Resize(name2.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 2, name2.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count - 7).Formula = [=IFERROR(INDEX('Request Tracker'!$K:$K,MATCH(Email.Template!R[]C5,'Request Tracker'!$G:$G,0)),"")]
```

## My original code has 3 subs

I need help with third sub which has the pasting of the formula

**1) The Calling**

```
Sub RUN()
Call AdvancedFilter
Call AdvancedFilterQC
End Sub
```

**2) The First Table**

```
Sub AdvancedFilter()
Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Range("B5:I20"), Sheet3.Range("B5:I20").End(xlDown)).Clear
    Dim source1 As Range
    Dim criteria1 As Range
    Dim output1 As Range
    Set source1 = Sheet1.ListObjects("RT").Range
    Set criteria1 = Sheet4.Range("A3").CurrentRegion
    Set output1 = Sheet3.Range("B3").CurrentRegion
    source1.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, criteria1, output1
End Sub
```

**3) The Second Table**

```
Sub AdvancedFilterQC()
    Dim output1 As Range
    Dim qcheader As Range
    Dim qctitle As Range
    Set output1 = Sheet3.Range("B3").CurrentRegion
    With output1
        Set qctitle = .Offset(.Rows.Count + 1).Cells(1, 1)
        Set qcheader = .Offset(.Rows.Count + 2).Cells(1, 2)
    End With
    Sheet4.Range("F18:M18").Copy qctitle
    Sheet4.Range("F19:J19").Copy qcheader
    Dim source2 As Range
    Dim criteria2 As Range
    Dim output2 As Range
    Set source2 = Sheet2.ListObjects("QCT").Range
    Set criteria2 = Sheet4.Range("A9").CurrentRegion
    Set output2 = qcheader.CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 1).Resize(qcheader.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, _
    qcheader.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count - 3)
    source2.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, criteria2, output2
    Dim name2 As Range
    Set name2 = output2
    Sheet4.Range("K19").Copy name2.Cells(1, 4)
    name2.CurrentRegion.Offset(2, 4).Resize(name2.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, _
    name2.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count - 7).Clear
    
name2.CurrentRegion.Offset(2, 4).Resize(name2.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 2, name2.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count - 7).Formula = [=IFERROR(INDEX('Request Tracker'!$K:$K,MATCH(Email.Template!R[]C5,'Request Tracker'!$G:$G,0)),"")]
      
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a followup question based of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77744000/23177311

Comment: `The Formula I want to across the range is` What's location of the range? The easy way to get the code is `record macro`.  Enable `record macro` when you apply formula by manual. You will get the code in a standard module.

Comment: `.Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Request Tracker'!$K:$K,MATCH(Email.Template!E14,'Request Tracker'!$G:$G,0)),"""")"`, usually without `Email.Template!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corrected line should look something like this:

```
name2.CurrentRegion.Offset(2, 4).Resize(name2.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 2, name2.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count - 7).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(INDEX('Request Tracker'!C11,MATCH(Email.Template!RC[-4],'Request Tracker'!C7,0)),"""")"
```

In this corrected version, I've used the FormulaR1C1 property, which allows you to set a formula using R1C1-style references.

Email.Template!RC[-4] refers to a cell in the current row (R[0]) and 4 columns to the left (C[-4]) on the 'Email.Template' sheet.

I just need to adjust the -4 according to the actual relative position of the cell I'm referring to.